# Check geolocation database using Classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have an IP address range database for determining country, but need a function written in **Classic ASP** that will find the range that the user's IP address fits into.

For example the database rows are like:

```
102.23.25.0   |  102.24.0.0   |  US
```

So if the IP address is 102.23.25.203 how can I find a match?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using your own dB tables and not other freely available and regularly updated services? If you can use something else, I have code for geoip down to city level and will add as an answer.

Comment: After reviewing all of the "free" services and resources I found that they are either not free at all, not accurate enough due to incomplete records, or require linking to offsite or third party resources which is a no-no.

Comment: Maxmind's geoip lite database is updated monthly and installed locally, plus has classic asp samples, I'd recommend it and can throw you a VBScript class that will do all the work. Then just add a scheduled task to update the dB file once a month and you're golden.

Comment: Yes I saw that. The free database doesn't include the whole IP address list.

Comment: @WilliamK what database are you using? is it a text file like you showed?

Comment: I thought that I checked out that Maxmind file. I can use that it it is what I suspect. Each row consists of start IP, end IP, a number, b number, country code, country name. What are the a and b numbers comprised of (how calculated). If they are what I suspect then I can easily write a Classic ASP script for this. 

Otherwise I can convert to numbers to produce for example   1013256003 from 1.13.256.3 which seems more logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the MaxMind CSV database I imported it into MS-SQL. Then wrote a simple Classic ASP routine to get the Country code.

```
strCheckIPnumber = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")

if strCheckIPnumber <> "" then
    strGeoArray = Split(strCheckIPnumber, ".")
    For i=0 to UBound(strGeoArray)
    Next            
    strGeo1 = strGeoArray(0)
    strGeo2 = strGeoArray(1)
    strGeo3 = strGeoArray(2)            
    strGeo4 = strGeoArray(3)

    strGeoNumber = strGeo1 * 16777216 + strGeo2 * 65536 + strGeo3 * 256 + strGeo4

    'response.write"GeoNumber = " & strGeoNumber & "<br>"

    SQLGeo = "SELECT Country FROM GeoLocation Where GeoLocation.StartNum <= '" & strGeoNumber & "' and GeoLocation.EndNum >= '" & strGeoNumber & "' "
    Set rsGeo = dbConnection.Execute(SQLGeo)    
    if NOT rsGeo.EOF then       
        strGeoCountry = rsGeo("Country").value
    end if
    rsGeo.Close
    Set rsGeo = Nothing

    response.write"GeoCountry = " & strGeoCountry & "<br>"

end if
```

Comment: I've created you a function for SQL that allows the testing of the different quads in an IP address for testing with SQL Server. Why not give it a test?

Comment: because the script above is perfect. It takes the IP address and converts it to a number that can be compared to the start and end numbers in the MaxMind database (see GeoNumber) which is the solution to the question... how to compare a given IP address to specified address ranges.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the user's IP address using `Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")` and then simply test the address segments...

```vbs
Function TestIp(testAddr, loIp, hiIp)
    Dim host, rLo, rHi, fail, i
    host = Split(testAddr, ".")
    fail = False
    rLo = Split(loIp, ".")
    rHi = Split(hiIp, ".")
    For i = 0 To 3
        'If one of the host values falls outside the range then it's all over...
        fail = CInt(host(i))<CInt(rLo(i)) Or CInt(host(i))>CInt(rHi(i))
        If fail Then Exit For
    Next 'i
    TestIp = fail
End If
```

**SQL Version**

We know for a certain fact that every IP can be broken into four. The command to do this is a mix of [`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [`SUBSTRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx).  Simply break down the test value into four and do the same for the low and high values then test each byte against the respective high and low.

Here's a function, which took me minutes to write, to do exactly that:

```sql
/*
    getIpQuad
        Returns the required quad of an IP address.
    Usage:
        SET @q2 = getIpQuad('127.0.0.1', 2)
    Parameters:
        @ip (STRING) - The IP address
        @quad (TINYINT) - The quad to retrieve (zero based)
*/
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getIpQuad] 
    (@ip AS VARCHAR(15), 
     @quad AS TINYINT)

RETURNS TINYINT AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @i AS TINYINT
    DECLARE @s AS TINYINT
    DECLARE @e AS TINYINT
    DECLARE @v AS VARCHAR(3)

    SET @s = 0
    SET @e = 0
    SET @i = 0

    WHILE @i<=@quad
    BEGIN
        SET @e = CHARINDEX('.', @ip, @s+1)
        IF  @e = 0 AND @s>1 SET @e = LEN(@ip)
        SET @v = SUBSTRING(@ip, @s+1, @e-@s)
        SET @s = @e
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

    RETURN (CAST(@v AS TINYINT))
END
```

**NOTE:** I have not included any bounds checking, it relies on the fact that you know what you're doing.

Comment: The IP address is already available and there will be hundreds of rows in the database table. The question is about checking it against each row where the low and high IP address is not a number. How can your script be used to run though each row in the database table?

Comment: @WilliamK: This is a server side function - you read your data into an array and test the IP against the elements of the array. If there are only hundreds it should be reasonably fast. Alternatively use SQL server. What have you tried so far - I notice no code in your OP?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like more of a DB question than VB.  A query something like the following should do it.

```
select locationName 
from IPLocationTable
where @inputIP >= IPStartRange
  and @inputIP <= IPEndRange
```

You issue this query using standard ADO data access, such as

```
sql = "put select statement here"
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.ConnectionTimeout = TIMEOUT
Conn.Open CONNECTIONSTRING
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
set rs.ActiveConnection = Conn
rs.Open sql,,adOpenForwardOnly,adLockReadOnly,adCmdText
set countryName =  rs("locationName")
rs.close
conn.close
```

Here's a test to show what I mean.  Note you have to modify the IP slightly to add leading zeros.

```
CREATE TABLE IPLocationTable(
    [StartIP] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EndIP] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Location] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
go
insert IPLocationTable(StartIP, EndIP, Location) values ('192.168.001.001', '192.168.001.255', 'Location1')
insert IPLocationTable(StartIP, EndIP, Location) values ('192.168.002.001', '192.168.002.255', 'Location2')
insert IPLocationTable(StartIP, EndIP, Location) values ('192.168.003.001', '192.168.004.255', 'Location3')
insert IPLocationTable(StartIP, EndIP, Location) values ('192.168.005.001', '192.168.006.255', 'Location4')
insert IPLocationTable(StartIP, EndIP, Location) values ('195.168.001.001', '196.168.001.255', 'Location5')
insert IPLocationTable(StartIP, EndIP, Location) values ('197.169.001.001', '198.169.001.255', 'Location6')
go

declare @myIP varchar(20)

set @myIP = '192.168.001.150'
select location from IPLocationTable where @myIP >= StartIP and @myIP <= endIP

set @myIP = '192.168.002.150'
select location from IPLocationTable where @myIP >= StartIP and @myIP <= endIP

set @myIP = '196.168.001.150'
select location from IPLocationTable where @myIP >= StartIP and @myIP <= endIP
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that the IP address will not be recognised as a number because it contains more than one dot (.). Perhaps I should convert the database records from IP addresses to integers.

Comment: I had assumed you were storing them as strings.  Strings will sort and compare correctly for this.

Comment: Sorting for an item between start-item and end.item needs integers.